# Ionic 2 back button in RTL layout

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm going to start an Ionic 2 app, and it should be in Arabic language, so i need to use RTL layout, i chose the side menu template

configuring the app to RTL by the following line changed every thing's direction perfectly except the back button should point to the right direction

```
<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage" dir="rtl"></ion-nav>
```

the navbar now looks like this

[image]

Isn't there any kind of fix until Ionic team gives attention to RTL related issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of setting the `dir` attribute in the `ion-nav`, you can use the platform to set the alignment to RTL ([docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#setDir))

```
private setProperAligment(): void {

    if (this.selectedLanguage.rtl) {
        this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);
        // ...
    } else {
        this.platform.setDir('ltr', true);
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will add the `dir="rtl"` attribute to the `html` tag of your app. Just like you said, Ionic team is working on fixing the issue with the back button, so in the meantime, you can add this css style rule in the `app.scss` file:

```
html[dir="rtl"] {
    .back-button-icon.icon-md.back-button-icon-md.ion-md-arrow-back {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .back-button-icon.icon-ios.back-button-icon-ios.ion-ios-arrow-back {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: in case of [dir="auto"]?

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 5 i faced the same issue and solved it by

```
document.dir = 'rtl';
```

before I followed the documentation where they say you have to mention the dir in the app.component.html whose example is below

```
<ion-app [dir]='dir'>
```

Where dir was my binded variable, every thing worked fine in that approach except the back button direction, After placing the document.dir = 'rtl'.
It solved that issue also. now in my language switcher button code i am only changing the document.dir.